# mod_rewrite and sub directory

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have issues configuring mod_rewrite for a website with this setup,
Website has a root installation for main language.
http://www.domain.com --> Main language (Lang 1).
And
http://www.domain.com/lang2 --> Secondary language (Lang 2) installed within a sub directory.

I have been able to successfully re-write urls for the main language using this simple line,

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+) index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

But I can't quite figure it out for the sub directory (Lang 2).

Lang 2 has same URL setup. (index.php?page=some-page

This **doesn't work**,

```
RewriteRule ^lang2/([a-z_-]+) lang2/index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to swap your two rules and use a `RewriteBase`.

Replace your current code by this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^lang2/([^/]+)$ lang2/index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Well, this worked better,  `^lang2/([a-z_-]+)$ lang2/index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]`